# Madrid Barajas Airport T2 arrival to T1 Depature with luggage one person 2 hours and 45 minutes, is it enough time?

Tags: transit, airport-transfer

Flying Aegean one way from Athens to Barrajas and arriving at 11:45 AM (almost always on time flight) with 1 bag checked luggage in T2, then taking a one way flight from Barrajas at 2:30 pm to Cancun Airport from T2. Is this enough time that I don't need to stress the whole trip? It's in July if that matters.

I know nobody knows for sure, but generally speaking is this a HUGE gamble?

Thank you in advance

Comment: One ticket or two?

Answer (score 3):

Aegean doesn't sell tickets to Cancun, so I assume these are two different tickets.

> I know nobody knows for sure, but generally speaking is this a HUGE gamble?

This really depends on your personal risk tolerance. The "likelihood" of missing the connection is low. However the "impact" of missing it is high: you are a no-show for your second flight and at the mercy of the airline. In the worst case, they will cancel your entire ticket and you have to buy a new one on the spot at "same day" prices.

If all goes well, this should be fine. Your first flight is Schengen to Schengen so there will be only minimal or no passport control involved. You will have to wait for your baggage, but it shouldn't take more than an hour from arrival to the check in counter of your second flight. Aer Europa, for example, closes check in 60 minutes before departure, so you would have 45 minutes to spare. Once you are checked in, you should be good. Even if security is unusually long they will most likely wait for you since otherwise they will have to unload your bags.

Things that can go wrong:

1. Your first flight is significantly delayed, cancelled, rebooked or the schedule is changed
2. They loose your bag. In this case you have to wait until the carrousel is empty before you can file a missing bag report.
3. Schedule change for your second flight.

Everyone feels differently about risk, so you have to decide for yourself if you are comfortable or not.

Personally, I don't do self-connections with less than 4 hours. More if there are  exacerbating circumstances.

Comment: I personally do not do self connections at all.

Comment: My guess is that the airline is “World 2 Fly” and their check-in deadline is one hour before departure. Even though it’s perfectly doable if all goes well, that really does not leave much margin for error. I certainly wouldn’t do it in those circumstances (I.e. with the second flight being the more expensive and infrequent of the two).

Comment: @Willeke: you don't know what you have been missing :-)